# How is a http request processed by Jboss if I used struts2

Tags: web-applications, struts2, jboss

I am interesting in how's a http request processed by web container like Jboss, supposed there are many `war` in JBoss, How does Jboss know a request should pass to one of them? And I want to if i had used `struts2`. How is reqeust finally passed to the `Action` of struts2 ? Can anybody help me to figure it out ? thanks.

**Updated**

say you have a same servlet mapping both in A.War and B.War like below . But they are different implement class of `HttpServlet`

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DeployServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/deploy/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

What happen to JBoss http request process order if the url is `/deploy/test`?

**Updated**

Let's make a **summany**, When the web container receive the Http Request to a certain resouce(*.html *.jsp etc), web container will choose a war application to process this request base on the context xml (like `server.xml` in `tomcat`). then, this war application will choose a servlet which defined in the Web.xml to handle the request firstly...

well, My question: 
`Filter` execute Http Request earlier than `Servlet`?

thanks.

Comment: we use to tell container about the struts2 filter dispatcher and also specify when to call it by mapping, have a look at web.xml, regarding how server know you need to know about server context and how it deply applications

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Help to review the updated content . thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all http request is received by the web server. Usually Servlet containers( like tomcat) and Application Servers (like JBoss) have an inbuilt web server.
So Web Server or also referred as http server gets request and decides if it can handle it.

**A web server can handle static content request like html, image etc.** If request is for a dynamic content then it passes the request to the Servlet container.

Servlet containers are part of Java EE servers (like Tomcat and JBoss AS). Servlet container has deployment desciptor (.xml files) through which it knows about all deployed applications. And when containers start these config files gets loaded (and gets converted into Object). So using deployment descriptor mapping it decides if the request is valid and if so then the request is send to appropriate resource (like servlet ).

For details you can read life cycle of Servlet and also how contaner works.

Answer (score 2):

The servlet-mapping will be relative to the application context.  If you deploy 2 wars they will have 2 different contexts.  If they don't you will get a deployment error.  You can set a war as the context root, so lets say you have 2 wars warA.war and warB.war
deployed to your server http://my_server.com

to access resources in either war you would use:

http://my_server.com/warA/somePage

or

http://my_server.com/warB/somePage

Using the mapping you described would look like http://my_server.com/warA/deploy/

If you set either war as the context root you could access the resource as http://my_server.com/deploy/ but the server is still translating that from /deploy to warA/deploy

So there would not be any confusion as to which servlet is retrieved.

Comment: You mean the request firstly goes to a certain implement class of `HttpServlet` if there exist .right ?thanks

Comment: No, the request first goes to the proper container (the war containing that servlet).  Take a look at the life cycle of a servlet section [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet), it does a pretty good explaining the process.